# Insert row based on values of existing rows in R

Tags: r

I have longitudinal data and I would like to insert new rows based on the values of multiple columns in existing rows.

For any individual, whenever there is a gap between the previous release date and next admission date, I would like to add a new row that has the previous release date as the admission date and the next admission date as the release date so there are no "gaps". If an individual's final observation has a release date, I would also like to add a new row with the previous release date as the admission date and NA for release date.

I think this might require data.table or dplyr's add_row but I'm not sure how. Other SO questions I have seen were based on the number of rows in a group or added new rows before/after every existing row. If I could figure out how to insert the rows in the right spots I think I can use dplyr's lag and lead functions to fill in the proper dates.

Here is some sample data:

```
myData <- data.frame(ID = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
                     TERM_TYPE = c("Parole", "Prison", "Parole",
                                   "Parole", "Prison", "Parole",
                                   "Parole", "Prison", "Parole", "Prison"),
                     ADMISSION_DATE = c("2006-10-15", "2008-09-15", "2009-01-15",
                                        "2006-01-15", "2006-12-15", "2006-12-15",
                                        "2006-04-15", "2013-01-15", "2013-12-15", "2015-01-15"), 
                     RELEASE_DATE = c("2008-09-15","2009-01-15", "2010-12-15",
                                      "2006-10-15", NA, "2008-06-15",
                                      "2010-01-15", "2013-12-15", "2015-01-15", NA), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would it to look like this:

```
   ID      TERM_TYPE ADMISSION_DATE RELEASE_DATE
1   2         Parole     2006-10-15   2008-09-15
2   2         Prison     2008-09-15   2009-01-15
3   2         Parole     2009-01-15   2010-12-15
4   2 Not supervised     2010-12-15         <NA>
5   3         Parole     2006-01-15   2006-10-15
6   3         Prison     2006-10-15         <NA>
7   4         Parole     2006-12-15   2008-06-15
8   4 Not supervised     2008-06-15         <NA>
9   5         Parole     2006-04-15   2010-01-15
10  5 Not supervised     2010-01-15   2013-01-15
11  5         Prison     2013-01-15   2013-12-15
12  5         Parole     2013-12-15   2015-01-15
13  5         Prison     2015-01-15         <NA>
```

Comment: Could you add the code what you've tried so far?

Comment: `padr::pad` may be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be more concise ways to do this, but I think this shows the underlying thinking. Basically, I combine three tables:

1) the original data
2) the missing gap periods
3) periods after a known release date

#2 and #3 are created by extracting relevant rows from the original and modifying them to show what we want. For instance, #2 finds the rows with gaps since the prior row, and modifies to make that row look like the missing period.

```
# First, change dates into date formats
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
myData <- myData %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("DATE")), ymd)

# Create table #2
myData_fill_gaps <- myData %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(gap_days = (ADMISSION_DATE - lag(RELEASE_DATE)) / ddays(1),
         ADM_temp = lag(RELEASE_DATE), 
         REL_temp = ADMISSION_DATE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(gap_days > 0) %>%  # Only keep rows relating to gaps
  mutate(TERM_TYPE = "Not supervised") %>%
  select(ID, TERM_TYPE, ADMISSION_DATE = ADM_temp, RELEASE_DATE = REL_temp)

# Create table #3
myData_add_release_NA <- myData %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%   # Only keep last row for each ID
  filter(!is.na(RELEASE_DATE)) %>%  # Only keep if lacking an NA in RELEASE_DATE
  mutate(TERM_TYPE = "Not supervised",
         ADMISSION_DATE = RELEASE_DATE,
         RELEASE_DATE   = NA_real_)

myData_combined <- bind_rows(
  myData,
  myData_fill_gaps,
  myData_add_release_NA
) %>%
  arrange(ID, ADMISSION_DATE)
```

Output

```
> myData_combined
   ID      TERM_TYPE ADMISSION_DATE RELEASE_DATE
1   2         Parole     2006-10-15   2008-09-15
2   2         Prison     2008-09-15   2009-01-15
3   2         Parole     2009-01-15   2010-12-15
4   2 Not supervised     2010-12-15         <NA>
5   3         Parole     2006-01-15   2006-10-15
6   3 Not supervised     2006-10-15   2006-12-15
7   3         Prison     2006-12-15         <NA>
8   4         Parole     2006-12-15   2008-06-15
9   4 Not supervised     2008-06-15         <NA>
10  5         Parole     2006-04-15   2010-01-15
11  5 Not supervised     2010-01-15   2013-01-15
12  5         Prison     2013-01-15   2013-12-15
13  5         Parole     2013-12-15   2015-01-15
14  5         Prison     2015-01-15         <NA>
```